# Dependency Injection - Get current Language

Tags: multilingual, dependency-injection

I am trying to make full use of Dependency Injection with Sitecore 9.3. The hardest part is getting away from using `Sitecore.Context`. I've been looking at ShowServicesConfig.aspx to try and find what to inject so I can access Sitecore.Context properties. One I am struggling with is `Sitecore.Context.Language`, what do I need to inject to be able to access the current language?

Comment: Are you trying to mock Sitecore.Context?

Comment: Sort of. Im trying to write testable code. I can write a wrapper around sitecore.context. BUT, it seems like more and more of the things in sitecore.context are already injectable.